# Do not fire custom validate on OnChange event of a textbox

Tags: asp.net, validation

I am using a custom validator to validate a textbox content.
Everytime the user leaves this textbox, my client script is called, which is, in my case, a little bit annoying.

I want the validation **only** to be performed when the user clicks on a button given button (which is already happening).
Is there any way to avoid the validation to be performed on the `OnChange` event of the `TextBox`?

My code is here:

```
function isGroupNameUnique(sender, args) {
        var valid = true;

        var tokens = $('#hdnGroupNames').val().split(',');
        var groupName = $('#<%= txtGroupName.ClientID %>').val();

        $.each(tokens, function (i) {
            if (groupName == this)
                valid = false;
        });

        args.IsValid = valid;
    }




<asp:TextBox ID="txtGroupName" runat="server" />

<asp:Button ID="btnAddGroup" runat="server" Text = "Add" onclick="btnAddGroup_Click" class="bGraySmaller" ValidationGroup="AddGroup"/>

<asp:CustomValidator  ID="validatorGroupNameAlreadyExists" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtGroupName" ErrorMessage="The Group Name has to be unique" ValidationGroup="AddGroup" ClientValidationFunction="isGroupNameUnique" />
```

Comment: My suggestion would be to remove the "ClientValidationFunction" attribute in the custom validator and add a jquery event handler for the "btnAddGroup" button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the ControlToValidate property on the [CustomValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eee01cx%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)(what is the only Validator where this property is not mandatory). Set the same ValidationGroup on the TextBox.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtGroupName" ValidationGroup="AddGroup" runat="server" />
<asp:CustomValidator  ID="validatorGroupNameAlreadyExists" runat="server" ErrorMessage="The Group Name has to be unique" ValidationGroup="AddGroup" ClientValidationFunction="isGroupNameUnique" />
```